# building a document preview webpage

Tags: print-preview

Hi i'm wanting to create a webpage in which i can pass a url to a document and it previews it. the idea behind this is so i can create a responsive web view for android so i can preview documents from with an app i have basic knowledge of php and html but if some one could point me in the right direction? i have had a look around but can't find anything that basic i don't need to edit the documents just view them. Does anyone know how to do this?

ps: the docs i want to preview are .xl .xls .doc .docx .pdf .ppt etc

Answer (score 0):

Here is what looks to be a decent open source option.

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to convert the documents to .pdf first using [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) and then preview them using [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)